# onActivityResult is not calling

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, onactivityresult

```
public void cameraIntent(Context context)
    {
        Intent takingPictureCameraintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            ((AppCompatActivity)context).startActivityForResult(takingPictureCameraintent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

            }

    }
```

This is my onActivityResult():

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(this,data);
        }
    }
```

onActivityResult() is not called. What should I do?

Comment: are you called from fragment or activity??

Comment: i think you are calling it from fragment.. if so, then try to call without.. `((AppCompatActivity)context).`.

Comment: nops.. calling from AppCompatActivity @sourabhbans

Comment: calling from activity.. @shweta

Comment: may be in cameraIntent ,correct parameter is not passed and if it so then resultCode is 0.

Comment: how will I verify it.

Answer (score 0):

onActivityResult will be called in the activity that you called startActivityForResult.

If you are doing this in your method "((AppCompatActivity)context)" your parameter should be an AppCompatActivity and not a Context.

For solving your problem, look where you are calling cameraIntent and what you are passing as parameter, it is in that activity that onActivityResult  will be called.

Comment: I am passing the calling activity context in the cameraIntent(). @jonathanrz

Comment: I will be very happy to add the code.If you can tell which code you are talking about. I think i have added enough code.   or you want me to add calling activity code? @jonathanrz